# Adding walls to a region plot

Tags: plotting

I've done this code:

```
Plot3D[x + y + 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= y <= Sqrt[x]]]
```

Producing this image:

[image]

In MATLAB, I used the mesh command:

```
u=linspace(0,1,40);
v=linspace(0,1,40);
[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
x=u;
y=v.*sqrt(u);
z=x+y+1;
h=meshz(x,y,z);
Z=get(h,'Zdata');
Z([1 end],:)=0;
Z(:,[1,end])=0;
set(h,'ZData',Z)
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
```

To produce this image:

[image]

Is there a Mathematica function that will add the walls to my first image?

Comment: `Filling -> Bottom`?

Comment: B´gosh, but that Matlab plot is hard on the eyes! @Kuba that deserves an answer!

Comment: `UnderstatementQ["hard on the eyes"]` `(*True*)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I like [gpap's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65065/52), it requires quite a bit of work. So, instead, use the built-in options.  The important one is [`FaceGrids`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html) which takes a list of vectors which specify which side the grid is on.

```
Plot3D[x + y + 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= y <= Sqrt[x]], 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, Boxed -> False, 
 Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Green, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaaaargh, facegrids dammit. I faintly remember using this at some point but it's not exactly common. +1 this is far better than mine!

Comment: @rollyer: How can you make the fill drop to the xy-plane (at z=0 instead of at z=1).

Comment: @David yes, add the option `PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}` to it.

Comment: Absolutely what I needed for my students. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

It will be easy to write a function that operates on the plot and takes the minimum value of each coordinate and adds a plane to combine the plots. I really don't have time to do this for you now so I've just copy-pasted some planes and changed the options to match the (uglier in my opinion) plotting style of MATLAB:

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[{0, y, z}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 1, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> "Neutral"],
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, 1, z}, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 1, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> "Neutral"],
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> "Neutral"],
  Plot3D[{x + y + 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= y <= Sqrt[x]], 
   Mesh -> 90, Filling -> Bottom, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Darker@Green, Opacity[1]]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 3}}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
 Boxed -> False, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image]

As I said, I can automate this but it'll have to wait until later/tomorrow if the above isn't satisfactory.